# C: Function working only in the first iteration

Tags: c, function, debugging, gdb

I am trying to design a pipelined cpu simulator. The code is fairly complex, atleast for me. There are multiple header and source files. The code compiles.

On running, it runs fine in the first iteration(clock cycle). But not so from the iteration. After spending hours on finding the fault, I found out what is wrong but don't know why. Following function:

```
MemoryAccess(ir, pc, ground, '0', instrMem);
```

fetches an instruction at index "pc" in instrMem and store it in "ir". Following are the declarations of the variables in the function:

```
typedef char bit32[33];
bit8 instrMem[4096];    /* instruction memory */
bit32 pc, ir, ground;
```

The problem is that from the second iteration onwards, value of "ir" remains "00000000". I have checked instrMem, the values are not all 0s. I also checked the working of MemoryAccess() using driver function. It works fine.

I can't undertand why it works fine for the first iteration and not from then on.

Can someone please help. Is there a way of finding out what's wrong?

following is the relevant part of main() function:

```
   for(cycle=0; ; cycle++) 
{
    /* load IR with PC value */
    printf("I am at the beginning of the cycle loop");
    MemoryAccess(ir, pc, ground, '0', instrMem); 

    /* report fetched register values */
    printf("cycle: %d, PC: %.32s (%d), IR: %.32s\n\t", cycle, pc, bit32toint(pc), ir);

    /* halt check */
    if (bit32toint(ir) == 0x0000003F) {
        printf("\nmachine halted\n");
        break;
    }

    /* PC + 4 data path */
    RCAdder_32(pcPlus4, ground, pc, "00000000000000000000000000000100", '0');

    /* jump data path */
    shiftleftby2(jumpAddress, ir);
    jumpAddress[0] = pcPlus4[0];
    jumpAddress[1] = pcPlus4[1];
    jumpAddress[2] = pcPlus4[2];
    jumpAddress[3] = pcPlus4[3];

    /* sign extended / shifted immediate data path */
    signextend(immSignExt, &ir[16]); 
    shiftleftby2(immShifted, immSignExt); 

    /* control unit data path */
    ControlUnit(ir, &ir[26], &regWrite, &regDest,
                    &memRead, &memWrite, &memToReg, 
                    &jump, &branch, &aluSrc, aluOp);

    /* register memory data path - read */
    Mux2_5(regWriteAddr, &ir[11], &ir[16], regDest);
    registerAccess(&regOut1, &regOut2, &ir[6], &ir[11], regWriteAddr, regIn, '0');

    /* alu data path */
    Mux2_32(aluSrcVal, regOut2, immSignExt, aluSrc);
    zero = ALU(&aluOut, regOut1, aluSrcVal, aluOp);

    /* branch data path */
    RCAdder_32(branchAddress, ground, pcPlus4, immShifted, '0');
    Mux2_32(mbranchAddress, pcPlus4, branchAddress, AND2_1(zero, branch));
    Mux2_32(pc, mbranchAddress, jumpAddress, jump);

    /* main memory data path */
    MemoryAccess(memOut, aluOut, regOut2, memWrite, mainMem);
    Mux2_32(regIn, aluOut, memOut, memToReg);

    /* register memory data path - write */
    registerAccess(&regOut1, &regOut2, &ir[6], &ir[11], regWriteAddr, regIn, regWrite);

    /* dump register memory and signal information */
    for (i=0; i < 14; i++) {
        inttobitn(i, 5, tmp);
        registerAccess(&regOut1, &regOut2, tmp, &ir[11], regWriteAddr, regIn, '0');
        printf("R%d: %d, ", i, bit32toint(regOut1));
    }
    printf("\b\b\n\tbranchAddress = %.32s (%d) jumpAddress = %.32s (%d)\n",
        branchAddress, bit32toint(branchAddress), jumpAddress, bit32toint(jumpAddress));
    printf("\topcode = %.6s, immSignExt = %.32s (%d), immShifted = %.32s (%d), PC+4 = %.32s (%d)\n",
        ir, immSignExt, bit32toint(immSignExt), immShifted, bit32toint(immShifted), pcPlus4, bit32toint(pcPlus4));
    printf("\tregWrite = %c, regDest = %c, memRead = %c, memWrite = %c, memToReg = %c, jump = %c, branch = %c, aluSrc = %c, aluOp = %.3s, zero = %c\n",
        regWrite, regDest, memRead, memWrite, memToReg, jump, branch, aluSrc, aluOp, zero);
    getchar();
}
```

Following is the MemoryAccess() function:

```
void MemoryAccess(bit32 read_out, bit32 addr, bit32 write_in, signal write_enable, bit8 memory[4096]){

int address= bitntoint(12, addr);
setbit8(read_out, memory[address]);
setbit8(&read_out[8], memory[address+1]);
setbit8(&read_out[16], memory[address+2]);
setbit8(&read_out[24], memory[address+3]);

if (write_enable){
    setbit8(memory[address], write_in);
    setbit8(memory[address+1], &write_in[8]);
    setbit8(memory[address+2], &write_in[16]);
    setbit8(memory[address+3], &write_in[24]);
}
```

}

Setbit8(a, b) copies b into a and appends '\0'.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see. Most likely, `ir` goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: Just a wild guess as you are not showing us the code..shouldn't you be passing the address of `ir` to `MemoryAccess`?

Comment: We need to see the relevant section of code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : Yeah, i understand. And its not possible to give the entire code here. But could you tell me a way to debug this issue? maybe using gdb or something else.

Comment: Add lots of print statements to the code and see where it first deviates from what you expect. Debugging is a skill gained from experience -- perhaps you can find an experiences programmer to walk you through it.

Comment: As `ir`'s content is set by `MemoryAccess()` the code for the latter would be the one of interest.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : True, I figured out what's wrong using the print statements. But still couldn't figure out why. I'll keep trying though. And thanks for the advice David

Comment: @alk : i have updated the question with MemoryAccess().

Comment: And what is `setbit8()` please?

Comment: @alk: Setbit8(a, b) copies b into a and appends '\0'.

Comment: @alk : Do you need more info on anything else?

Comment: Code please. And btw: Are you aware that passing `'0'` as value to `write_enable` this value is most likely interpreted as `true` as it equals `48`? What is `signal`?

Comment: @alk : typdef char* signal

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment:

1 The code shown does not seem to be increasing `pc`.

2 Although you pass `'0'` as writabel flag, it is not used as intended. You might like to change

```
if (write_enable)
```

to be

```
if (write_enable && ('0' != (*write_enable)))
```

Due to the former version `memory` is overwritten with what is referenced by the pointer passed into as 3rd parameter (`write_in`), which propably are `0`s.